# how to insert updated records in sqlite from sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite

In my app i have fetch records from sql server and store in sqlite on button click and this is working fine but my problem is on every button click the number of records gets doubled. for e.g. if sql server has 50 records, sqlite fetches 50 records on first button click on second button click the records are 100 and so on.

i want sqlite to store number of records same as sql server. I searched this thing but did not understand also im new in android. Any help will be appreciated and sorry if my question is unclear.

this is the code am using for inserting records in sqlite.

```
    public boolean insertUserData(String user_id, String user_pwd,String ff_code, String ff_name, String terr_code, String dg_code,String dist_code,  String ff_mob,String ff_mgr, String imeino) {
    Log.e(" inserting user details", "yes");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_USER_ID, user_id);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_USER_PWD, user_pwd);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_FF_CODE, ff_code);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_FF_NAME, ff_name);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TERR_CODE, terr_code);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DG_CODE, dg_code);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DIST_CODE, dist_code);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_FF_MOB, ff_mob);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_ff_mgr, ff_mgr);
    contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_IMEI_NO, imeino);
    db.insert("user_detail", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution is  :

It will Inseret N-Times (By Button Click)

```
INSERT  INTO book(id, name) VALUES(1001, 'Programming')
```

Try to Reproduce this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO book(id, name) VALUES(1001, 'Programming')
```

Another solution is:

Check Primary Key Is already Inserted or not

```
public boolean CheckAcnoFound(int acno) 
{
        Cursor curchkacno;

        curchkacno = mCon.DataFetch("select acno from acledger where acno="
                + acno );
        if (curchkacno.getCount() != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Insert Records:

```
if (CheckAcnoFound((Integer.parseInt(xAcLedgerAcNo)))
{

Your Code
}
```

DataFetch Method:

```
public Cursor DataFetch(String xQuery) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(xQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a field as `PRIMARY KEY` in `user_detail` table definition to prevent inserting duplicate records. It seems that `user_id` is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the server's data can change, you must delete any old data before inserting the new one.

If your rows have an unchanged ID declared as PRIMARY KEY, you can use [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead of `insert`.

Comment: yes server data will not always remain same it will change.  i made primary key but still my problem is same. can u show me with any sample code how to delete old data.

Comment: Replace `insert` with `replace`.